# Why Bootstrap 3 navbar dropdown doesn't work in IE8?

Tags: css, internet-explorer, twitter-bootstrap, navbar

The bootstrap 3 dropdown doesn't work in IE8, I don't know why, any help on that. some people say because BS added CSS filter property

Comment: possible duplicate of [Bootstrap dropdown not working in IE8](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15987426/bootstrap-dropdown-not-working-in-ie8)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Twitter bootstrap 3 RC2 - Navigation in IE8 not working](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18286892/twitter-bootstrap-3-rc2-navigation-in-ie8-not-working)

Comment: I had this issue but without your html I cannot assume my resolution would work.  For me, my IE menu drop downs failed because I was using <menu> instead of <ul> tags.  The bootstrap 3 navbar samples clearly show <ul> tags in use.

Answer (score 18):

bootstrap3 workes fine with ie 8 only you have make sure to add respond.js , html5shiv and latest version of jQuery

like this:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">
 <!--[if lt IE 9]>
  <script src="js/html5shiv.js"></script>
  <script src="js/respond.min.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
```

Comment: +1 adding the shiv and respond scripts to the head element worked for me.

Comment: Also, respond.js will only work if you're hosting the bootstrap css files yourself, not loading from a CDN.

Answer (score 2):

I have tested this so many time in localhost.It will never work in localhost,Jut upload the same folder on your server and then check it will 100% work.

Answer (score 0):

Include these two script:

```
<script type='text/javascript' src="http://html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/respond.js/1.4.2/respond.js"></script>
```

Then use jQuery version LESS than 2 (jQuery 2++ doesn't support IE8 anymore)

Finally, use a web server (local or otherwise) to view your site because respond.js doesn't play well with file:// protocol

Answer (score 0):

Found this on another thread but revert your jquery to version 1.11.2 instead of 2+.

Answer (score 0):

To solve the problem on the same server you host your site compatibility files ( html5shiv and Respond ) and will have , again , host the bootstrap files and not use the CDN . Otherwise compatibility with IE 8 will not operate.