# Bootstrap 3 navbar dropdown, I lost support in IE8+, what did I do wrong?

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

So when I use Internet Explorer 10 in compatibility mode on IE8 or IE9, and I go to this page:
http://getbootstrap.com/components/#navbar
, then the dropdown behaves as expected. Now I've tried to implement the same thing on a website, this one:
http://www.fransmoret.nl/producten
, and now the dropdown doesn't seem to work properly in IE8 / IE9 mode anymore.

Can anybody tell me what I did wrong?

Comment: Pls check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18486163/why-bootstrap-3-navbar-dropdown-doesnt-work-in-ie8

Comment: I used modernizr, didn't work. I tried that answer, also didn't work.

Comment: what about respond.js.. check if media query is supported after adding that

Comment: I added respond.js. What do you mean by media query?