# Bootstrap navbar sample always showing mobile on desktop

Tags: asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap, visual-studio-2012

I copied the navbar default sample from [from the samples](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#navbar-default) but without any changes it appears to be doing what I think is mobile format. The only thing I see is the brand tag to the left and the button to the right. My monitor is pretty big so it can handle the menu and it does when I view it online which you can visually see [here](http://getbootstrap.com/examples/navbar-fixed-top/). I can only assume that since I cut and paste from the demo code I have a setting somewhere else that is wrong but I have no idea where to look. I did make sure to run nuget and get the latest version of the code so I should match what is on the demo. Any ideas?

**Update**

The issue appears to be with VS2012 and debug mode. Using Visual Studio Development Server seems to be the problem. If I publish locally it works as expected. I thought it might be IE8 but realized it was VS2012 after I published the site.

Is there a way to work around this while using the debugger in VS2012?

**Update 2**
And somehow it is not working in IE8 again even after being published. Chrome seems to work fine. Must be something picky about IE8 that I need to code around.

Comment: Looking at the documentation I also did a test from the Grid System section under examples for mobile and desktop. In my index.cshtml I tried to create 3 simple columns using div class="row" and nested div class="col-md-4". It will always shows the columns vertically. To force it I have to use class="col-xs-4" and then they columns show horizontally as expected. I've read the default is mobile but it should recognize desktop from what I read. I suspect something buried in my MVC application but my _layout.cshtml looks fine.

Answer (score 1):

Try to copy all the page html, then if it works cut unnecessary code.
Use this instead of your local bootstrap:

```
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<!-- Optional theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this was an issue with IE8 all along. I didn't think it was a browser issue so I never looked for IE8 nav problems but [here is a link that documents the issue.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18486163/why-bootstrap-3-navbar-dropdown-doesnt-work-in-ie8)