# Bootstrap dropdown menu jumbing on hover in ie8

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-8

i have bootstrap dropdown menu which is working fine in all the browser other than IE8, can anyone look into this and help me please

```
.navbar.navbar-default ul li:hover{
            .dropdown-menu {
                display: block;
                }
        }



.dropdown-menu {
  background-image: url(../pics/Responsive/dropdown-bg.png);
  background-size: 100% auto;
  background-position: top left;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-color: transparent;
  top: 100%;
  left: 10%;
  position: absolute;
  text-align: center;
  border: 0;
  box-shadow: none;
  width: 1048px !important;
  float: none !important;
  margin: 0 auto !important;
  top: 56px !important;
  min-height: 200px!important;
  border: 0 none !important;
  padding: 10px 6% 0;
  -ms-behavior: url(backgroundsize.min.htc);
}
```

thx in advance, can anyone help on this issue?

Comment: Could you please create a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that reproduces the issue? Just looking at CSS won't help too much. (and on a side note, why so many `!important`s??? Try to avoid using them like the plague.)

Comment: I recommend you read this [Why Bootstrap 3 navbar dropdown doesn't work in IE8?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18486163/why-bootstrap-3-navbar-dropdown-doesnt-work-in-ie8)

Comment: @MikeK thx for reply!!! this is fixed as i had to change some css since i was using backgroundsize.min.htc to make work background-image   proerty in IE8.. now dropdown jumbing is fixed, am very much happy now :)

Comment: @Ashesh  thx for your time. i gone through that,but actually in my case navbar was working without any issue, but some jumbing was there, now its alrightnow.